# Angular ngAnimate module will break my open layers map directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, openlayers, ng-animate

I've made a directive that display an Open Layers map (below is not my production code, but a simplified version used to create a plunkr. Don't pay attention to the hardcoded DOM element ID).

*EDIT : the hardcoded ID was indeed the issue, see comments below...*

```
app.directive('tchOlMapCopy', function () {

    return {

        restrict: 'E',

        replace: true,
        template: '<div id="tchMap" class="full-height"></div>',

        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            var map = new OpenLayers.Map("tchMap");
            map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());
            map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(3, 47).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")), 5);
        }
    }
```

I had that issue that, when I change route in my app an go from one screen including that directive to another, the map won't display on the second screen. The link function in the directive isn't even called.

I've narrowed down the issue to be related to ngAnimate module. If I remove dependency to this module, the map will display correctly on second route change.

[I've made a Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0tXsWS0DXtl37jV8GywI?p=preview) to illustrate this issue. Comment or uncomment the ngAnimate module in app.js file to see the issue.

Does anybody have an idea why ngAnimate breaks my directive call ?

Comment: First, having multiple instance of this directive which has an *hardcoded `id`* seems a very bad idea. Should be a *unique identifier* : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#id

Comment: That's not my "real" code, I just copied my directive and simplified it to make it work in plunkr. Above is a paste from plunkr. I'll add a note so others don't get mistaken, thank you.

Comment: Ho ho, the hard coded ID was indeed the issue, my bad... Seems like I'm not used to some common pitfalls of SPA yet ^^. Stupid me. Bounty's yours if you provide an answer below, so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having multiple instance of this directive which has an *hardcoded* `id` seems a very bad idea. Should be a unique identifier : http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#id